# Emulator: glMatrixMode:1558 GL err 0x506

Tags: android

I am facing this error Emulator: glMatrixMode:1558 GL err 0x506 when i run my app and get list of this errors and application crash.

Even I extend the RAM of my virtual device 3072MB but still facing this error.

Comment: Please share some code, android version, SDK version, etc.

Comment: I am  using android  SDK 3.0.1
=================================
            String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
            if (encoding == null) {
                encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
            }
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), encoding));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Comment: Even I change my Emulator resolution my computer resolution 1366 X 786 and Emulator 400 X 800 

But can not solve the problem.